# Why android ACTION_USER_PRESENT broadcast

Tags: android, android-emulator, device

Here is the code for Manifest

```
        <receiver android:name=".PowerButtonBroadcastreciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And here goes the part of  the reciever

```
package com.example.rakshaprotectingwomen;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PowerButtonBroadcastreciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static int pressCount;
    public PowerButtonBroadcastreciever()
    {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())){
                pressCount++;
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Power Button","On");}
            if(pressCount>=2)
            starter(context);


    }
    private void starter(Context context)
    {
        pressCount=0;
        Toast.makeText(context,"Started Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

So How do I solve this issue basically ?
P.s I tried couple of things like trying on different devices Like a ViVO , a Samsung device no where it works , as I am not getting the toast messages, but emulators it works perfectly

Comment: What is the issue? What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? You might find it helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ah hey @StackUnderflow The issue was I was unable to make a broadcast register work on my physical device, which works fine on the emulator, Thanks for reaching to me, but I solved it.
It was the issue because some of the native intents are not allowed by android to register statically in the Manifest, we need to register them dynamically.